# memcache entities without ReferenceProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

I have a list of entities which I want to store in the memcache. The 
problem is that I have large Models referenced by their 
ReferenceProperty which are automatically also stored in the memcache. 
As a result I'm exceeding the size limit for objects stored in 
memcache.

Is there any possibility to prevent the ReferenceProperties from 
loading the referenced Models while putting them in memcache?

I tried something like

```
def __getstate__(self): 
    odict = self.__dict__.copy() 
    odict['model'] = None 
    return odict
```

in the class I want to store in memcache, but that doesn't seem to do 
the trick.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:** I verified by adding a logging-statement that the `__getstate__`-Method is executed.

Comment: +1. Are you sure __getstate__ is executed?

Comment: I tend to store Keys in properties other than ReferenceProperties to avoid this and other issues related to the lazy-loading, but I assume that's not the answer you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

For large entities, you might want to manually handle the loading of the related entities by storing the keys of the large entities as something other than a ReferenceProperty.  That way you can choose when to load the large entity and when not to. Just use a long property store ids or a string property to store keynames.

Answer (score 0):

```
odict = self.copy()
del odict.model
```

would probably be better than using **dict** (unless getstate needs to return dict - i'm not familiar with it). Not sure if this solves Your problem, though... You could implement **del** in Model to test if it's freed. For me it looks like You still hold a reference somewhere.

Also check out the pickle module - you would have to store everything under a single key, but it automaticly protects You from multiple references to the same object (stores it only once). Sorry no link, mobile client ;)

Good luck!